# If statment based on part of string in Python

Tags: python, string, if-statement

I'm learning Python and I have a problem with if statement based on part of a string. I'm looking for an answer but I didn't find anything useful.

I have a list of few (15) names grouped in 3 subgroups:

```
'axxxxxxxx_44'
'bxxxxxxxx_22'
'cxxxxxxxx_2'
```

i've created a few methods for editing that files and now I put it into 'for' loop. For every edited subgrup is created separated directory and i need to put the result depends of _xx.

How can I do that by if statement?

Now all my files are generated in same, main directory.

Code for example:

```
try:
    for i in range(0, len(dir_names)):
        os.mkdir(dir_names[i])
except FileExistsError:
    print("Directory ", dir_names[i], " already exists")

for x in range(0, len(file_names)):
    fileName = '{}'.format(file_names[x])
# here I need (I know how to change dir but problem with if on string):
# if string is ended by _44 change working directory on directory named _44
# else if _22 change working directory on directory named _22
# else _02 to _02
    fileIn = fileName + "{}".format('')
    fileFixed = fileName + "{}{}".format('_out', '.txt')
    fileFinalCSV = fileName + "{}{}".format('_out', '.csv')
```

Comment: `dir_name = 'axxxxxxxx_44'[1:8]`

Comment: Read also about [Format examples](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#format-examples)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few ways you can do this.

1. Check the string directly:

   ```
   if dir_name == 'axxxxxxxx_44'
   ```

   or

   ```
   if '_44' in dir_name
   ```
2. Using [str.endswith()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith):

   ```
   if dir_name.endswith('_22')
   ```
3. Using [str.split()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

   ```
   if dir_name.split('_')[1] == '44'
   ```

There are a virtually unlimited number of options, and depending on your specific situation the one that you should use will vary.  For this example I would use option 2.

Comment: Very useful answer! Thank u!